# Coded ui - Cannot perform 'SetProperty' to textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, coded-ui-tests

I am writing a coded ui to WPF application.
The project contain about 30 test and at test initilaize i have method which commit Login.
The problem is that in some cases i get the error:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.PlaybackFailureException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Cannot perform 'SetProperty of Text with value "admin"' on the control. Additional Details: 
TechnologyName:  'UIA'
ControlType:  'Edit'
AutomationId:  'UserName'
```

Most of the time this error doesnt happen.

i have difficulty to found bug Consistency.

i can say that if i will restart the agent service and will run the 30 test - i will not have this error.
but if i will run 10 test - no service restart- run again 10 test i will have possibility error reproduce.

Full error log:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.PlaybackFailureException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Cannot perform 'SetProperty of Text with value "admin"' on the control. Additional Details: 
TechnologyName:  'UIA'
ControlType:  'Edit'
AutomationId:  'UserName'

  Source=Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting
  BasicMessage=Cannot perform 'SetProperty of Text with value "admin"' on the control.
  HResult=-268111863
  Action=SetProperty of Text with value "admin"
  ObjectName=UserName
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowComException(COMException innerException, IPlaybackContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(SystemException exception, IPlaybackContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(SystemException exception, String actionName, UITestControl uiControl)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(SystemException exception, String actionName, Object parameterValue, UITestControl uiControl)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.SetPropertyValue(String propertyName, Object propertyValue)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.SetProperty(String propertyName, Object value)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WpfControls.WpfEdit.set_Text(String value)

  InnerException: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
       Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0xF004F006
       Source=Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback
       ErrorCode=-268111866
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.Engine.IScreenElement.SetValueAsEditBox(String bstrNewValue, Int32 nSetValueAsEditBoxFlag)
            at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.SetValueAsEditBox(String value, Boolean isEncoded, Int32 flag)
            at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.SetValueAsEditBox(String value, Boolean isEncoded)
            at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.TechnologyElementPropertyProvider.SetValueAsEditBox(UITestControl uiControl, String value, Boolean isEncoded, Boolean useCopyPaste)
            at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WpfPropertyProvider.SetEditProperty(String propertyName, Object value)
            at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WpfPropertyProvider.SetPropertyValue(UITestControl uiControl, String propertyName, Object value)
            at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestPropertyProvider.SetPropertyValueWrapper(UITestControl uiControl, String propertyName, Object value)
            at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.SetPropertyValue(String propertyName, Object propertyValue)
       InnerException:
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to IE. You may want to consider the workaround temporarily by uninstalling the updated version of IE.
For this,
*(1)Open About IE*
*(2) Click on Checkbox that says "Uninstall IE new version updates automatically"*
*(3) Click ok.*
This New version (KBxxxxxxxx) comes up as a Windows Security Update on Installed Updates. You may want to consider the workaround temporarily, but be aware that you would be uninstalling an important Security Update.